# How do I set permissions recursively on a dir (with ACL enabled)?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, acl

For example, I want to give my colleagues write access to certain directory. Let's assume that subdirectories in it had access rights 775, files 664, and also there were some executable files in the dir - 775.

Now I want to add write permissions. With chmod, I could try something like

```
chmod o+w -R mydir/
```

But that's not cool, since I don't want to make the dir world-writable - I want give access only to certain users, so I want to use ACL. But is there an easy way to set those permissions? As I see it, I need to tackle at least three cases (dirs, files, executable files) separately:

```
find -type d -exec setfacl -m u:colleague:rwx {} \;
find -type f -executable -exec setfacl -m u:colleague:rwx {} \;
find -type f \! -executable -exec setfacl -m u:colleague:rw {} \;
```

It seems quite a lot of code lines for such a simple task. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`setfacl` has a *recursive* option (`-R`) just like `chmod`:

> ```
>   -R, --recursive
>       Apply operations to all files and directories recursively. This
>       option cannot be mixed with `--restore'.
> ```

it also allows for the use of the capital-x `X` permission, which means:

> ```
>   execute only if the file is a directory or already has
>   execute permission for some user (X)
> ```

so doing the following should work:

```
setfacl -R -m u:colleague:rwX .
```

(all quotes are from `man setfacl` for *acl-2.2.52* as shipped with Debian)

Comment: setfacl does not have the '-R' flag in FreeBSD 9

Comment: then it's good that the OP tagged their question as [linux]

Comment: Missed that.  ;)

Comment: Does this automatically apply to new files/folders created within afterwards?

Comment: Check the man page for your version of setfacl.  The option `-X` doesn't work as expected in  included in `setfacl 2.2.49`.

Comment: @phyatt It's not a `-X` option, it's a permission (`rwX` as opposed to `rwx`)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by umläute, the command `setfacl -R` with uppercase "X" is the way to go, like:

```
setfacl -R -m u:colleague:rwX .
```

However, for those who need to **re-apply ACL recrusively** (i.e like "re-apply permissions on sub-directories" à la Windows).

```
find . -mindepth 1 | xargs -n 50 setfacl -b --set-file=<(getfacl . | sed -e 's/x$/X/')
```

That command could be splited to avoid error like `setfacl: foobar: Only directories can have default ACLs`.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d| xargs -n 50 setfacl -b --set-file=<(getfacl . | sed -e 's/x$/X/')
find . -mindepth 1 -type f| xargs -n 50 setfacl -b --set-file=<(getfacl . | grep -v '^default:' | sed -e 's/x$/X/')
```

Note that the syntax `<( something )` is *Process Substitution*, which is specific to bash. You may need to create a temporary file if you use another shell.

Answer (score 2):

Always if you want to give recursive permission on dir only read then always use `r-x` .

Use given CMD : `setfacl -Rm u:user_name:permission /location/abc/xyz`

Example with explanation:   `setfacl -Rm u:admin12:r-x /appl/work/load/`

```
         Here `setfacl` : used to set permission.
               -Rm      : R for recursive and m for modify those old permission on given path. 
                u       : User which u want to add with given permission.
                admin12 : its an user , same user wants permission for a given location.
                
        /appl/work/load : Set a location where you want to give permission.
```

Comment: Thanks for giving details about **all** the options used. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in $(find /data -mindepth 0 -type d)
do setfacl -m  u:zabbix:r-x $i
    echo "ACL rules set for "$i
done
```

Comment: [Do not use `for i in $(find …)`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @muru Out of curiosity, why not?

Comment: The whole comment is a link. Follow it and find out.

Comment: If you want to go this approach use `find /data -mindepth 0 -type d -exec setfacl -m u:zabbix:r-X {} \;`

Comment: Do not use it. `$(find /data -mindepth 0 -type d)` will not return results line by line, it will buffer the whole results. If there is a space in a line, you will get an incorrect record in `$i` variable.

Comment: @muru +1 for interesting. Even if it's out of mere curiosity.